# C language function error

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

#define java2 "5"
#define java3 "five"
#define java4 "Five"
#define java5 "FIVE"

 main(void)
 {
printf("Few question to cheer you up \n\n\n");
printf("How many class are there in Java\n");
scanf("%s",class);

if(class==java2 || class==java3 || class==java4 || class==java5 ){
     goto Okay;
}

else{
    printf("incorrect answer \n\n");
}

system("pause");
exit(0);

Okay:
{
printf("Welcome");
system("pause");
}

  return 0;
}
```

when i answer the question correctly,it will print incorrect answer and exit
and if i use this instead;

```
if(class=5 || class=five || class=Five || class==FIVE ){
goto Okay;
}
```

it will print compiler error "[error] FIVE undeclared(first use in this function)"

please help me out,i just start writing C language last week.

Comment: For string comparison use `strcmp()`. Using `==` tests the pointers themselves. Also `class` is not defined *(and will clash with a C++ keyword if you ever use that language for this program)* which makes this an uncompilable code.

Comment: use `strcmp()` from  `#include <string.h>` and never use `goto`

Comment: i thinking of jumping straight to other line. what can i use apart from goto ?

Comment: Also your code uses `=` which is assignment, not comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was some mistakes with your code: never use `goto`; don't use `C` or `C++` keywords as variable names, like `class`; no need to use `exit(0)` and `return 0` in the same time

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define java2 "5"
#define java3 "five"
#define java4 "Five"
#define java5 "FIVE"

int main()
{
    char input[10];
    printf("Few question to cheer you up \n\n\n");
    printf("How many class are there in Java\n");
    scanf("%s", input);

    if ( (strcmp(input, java2) == 0) || (strcmp(input, java3) == 0) || (strcmp(input, java4) == 0) || (strcmp(input, java5) == 0) )
    {
        printf("Welcome. \n\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Incorrect answer! \n\n");
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

You have defined

```
#define java5 "FIVE"
```

in other words, you have defined it as a string. But in order to compare strings, you need to use `strcmp()` and not `==`, for example

```
if ( (strcmp(class, java5) == 0) || (strcmp(class, java4) == 0) ||... ){
    ....
}
```

Comment: @Adelabufred I am glad that I helped. I would really appreciate it if you accepted my answer, as long as it was useful to you :)

Comment: @Adelabufred if it worked, accept the answer, so that it doesn't appear as unanswered in the question feed, please.

Answer (score 2):

The `==` sign does not compare strings. USe:

```
if (strcmp(class, java3)==0 || ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of comparing charecter array with == use strcmp function
Also dont use goto keyword its a bad habbit of coding instead of that use flag Like
    int flag=0;
    If(condition)
    {
    flag=1;
    }
    If(flag==1)
    {
    }